# Why does the iteration not continue after the first row?

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, nested, nested-lists

I'm taking nested lists and trying to get them to print like so.

input [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8,9]]

output
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5
6 | 7 | 8 | 9

```
user_input= input()
lines = user_input.split(',')
mult_table = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in lines]

for row in mult_table:
    length = len(row)
    i = 0

    while i < length:
        row.insert(i + 1 , ' | ')
        i += 2
    for cell in row:
        print (cell, end='')
    print()
```

I expected this to iterate through each string, but instead, it only iterated through the first string.

output was
1 | 2 | 3
45
6789

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the approach that you can use here:

```
mult_table = [[1,2],[3,4],[2,3,4,5]]

delim = " | "

for row in mult_table:
    print(delim.join(map(str, row)), end = " ")
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I haven't read anything about the map function yet, so I assume that's not the approach that I'm supposed to take. Any other ideas??  I tried doing something similar with end = " | " and it was almost correct except there was a vertical line at the end of the line also.